# How do I create a loop that squares an integer until it reaches a certain number of digits?

Tags: python

The task:

> Using python, create a function that uses a loop to determine how many
> times a number can be squared until it reaches at least a twenty eight
> digit number.
>
> Ex: It takes three times to reach a three digit number, starting with
> 2: 2^2 = 4, 4^2 = 16, 16^2 = 256

Below is what I've tried:

```
def squaring():
    maximum = int(len(28))
    for i in range(3, maximum):
        print(i**2)
```

I've also tried:

```
def squaring():
    i = 3
    while len(str(i)) < 28:
        i = i ** 2
        print(i)
```

Comment: Your second attempt looks fine, but doens't count the number of iterations. The first simply loops over `range(3, 2)` which is obviously nonsense.

Comment: Your second attempt works well, just need to add another variable that takes into account the number of times it has looped.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example doesn't work, as `len` is not defined for integers.

Your second example is actually quite right: You can add a counter to check how many times you've multiplied the original number:

```py
def squaring():
    counter = 0
    i = 3
    while len(str(i)) < 28:
        i = i ** 2
        counter += 1
        print(i)
    return counter
print(f'The number of squares: {squaring()}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really necessary to convert anything to a string. It can be done like this:

```
def count_squares(n):
    count = 0
    while n < 10**27+1:
        n *= n
        count += 1
    return count
print(count_squares(3))
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

A Update to the function you created, just passing a parameter to pass number of your choice and adding a iterator **'i'** in order to get x-times the number is squared

```
def squaring(input_number):
    number = input_number
    i = 0
    while len(str(number)) <= 28:
        number = number ** 2
        i += 1
        print(number)
    return str(i)+'x'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can transform the number into a string and you evaluate the len `len(str(i**2))` and put a condition

Answer (score -1):

You can Use `While True` until your  Conditions occur!

‍‍

```
_iter = 0
i = 2
while True:
    i = i**2
    _iter += 1
    if len(str(i)) >=28:
        break
    
print(_iter)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).